# Two types of associations with user with has_many, :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model User. Users can own an object. Users can also send objects to one another. I am trying to access all "senders" to a user, such that I can access @user.senders and get all the unique senders to that user. This is my setup:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :senders, through: :object_relationships, source: :user, class_name: "User"
  has_many :object_relationships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_objects, inverse_of: :user

  has_many :objects, through: :object_relationships
  has_many :object_relationships
end

class ObjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :object
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should not name your model `Object`, since that class has special meaning in ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html

Comment: Also, you want to access all senders of a user? But in your models right now, a user does not have senders, an object has senders (through object relationships). Please clarify which you want.

Comment: I'm using Object as a placeholder here just for generalizability so others may easier understand. I want to be able to access senders from users and objects. Right now, it's set up to get from objects only, but even that doesn't work as it says the 'senders' model isn't recognized.

Comment: I've tested it and adding senders to an object (which I renamed `MyObject`) works fine. Are you actually using the class name `Object`? That will likely cause problems, even in a simple test case like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :gift_senders    
  has_many :senders, through: :gift_senders, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_gifts, class_name: 'Gift', foreign_key: :user_id

  has_many :gift_senders    
  has_many :accepted_gifts, through: :gift_senders, source: :gift
end

class GiftSender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gift
end
```

I've renamed your model to gift just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Accepted gift wasn't working how you did it. Instead, this seems to work. Is there anything wrong with it?:

has_many :accepted_gifts, :class_name => "Gift", inverse_of: :user